# AWS Cognito User Pool Identity Sign-In user REST API

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I can't find the [REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html?shortFooter=true) for Signing-In a user to a User Pool Identity.
It's of course possible with the various SDKs available, but what I don't want to depend on an SDK?

[Sign-Up](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SignUp.html) or [Confirm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ConfirmSignUp.html?shortFooter=true) a user was done easily using REST APIs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SDK's are just thin wrappers around the API. Cognito is not a rest API, it uses POST and a target prefix header via Http 1.1.

Signin is a higher level flow than simply hitting the service. You'll want to start here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html

You may want to check out the Android or iOS sdks and mimic their behavior on the auth flow.